# Automation test java Applet

Tags: automation

I am working on writing Automation test for the company, written on Java Applet, but currently the test tool Selenium does not support but have to use test tool with license, but now my customers want another way that does not use the tool with license , I have not found a way, please ask everyone to teach me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: For coding, you could use a java screen reader library like http://sikulix.com.  Alternatively, you could use an RPA ("Robotic Process Automation") tool;  Both www.uipath.com and www.automationanywhere.com (to name two, but there are probably others) have free Community Editions.    On another note : Why on earth is anyone still using Applets ???

Comment: Currently we have a long-written application, I want to be automation test for that application, but Selenium does not support, I want to find a tool that supports my work well.

Comment: See how you get on with the links.  Instead of giving selenium an ID,etc to find, you give Sikuli an image of the button (or whatever) to find on the screen - it works pretty well.   Alternatively, UiPath and AutomationAnywhere are applications in their own right, so instead of writing a program you use their front-end.  Good luck :)

Comment: UIPath is not open source, it has a very high cost :(

Comment: As I said, UiPath (and AutomationAnywhere and probably others ) has a free CommunityEdition.  Still, probably Skkuli is closest in intent to Selenium, so maybe give hat a shot first.